# How to extract unspecified links from html in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I haven't found a good answer to my question about extracting links from an HTML document. I've seen some answers where you specify the link directly. However, what if you wanted to extract an unspecified url? I am just wondering if that is possible. I have this HTML here

I put this into Pycharm

```
html = """
<
<html>
<head>
    <title>About me</title>

</head>

<body>
<h1>About Me</h1>

<h4>My Hobbies</h4>
<a href="http://www.google.com"> hello world </a>
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com">byeworld </a>

<ul>
    <li>Cooking</li>
    <li>Gym</li>
    <li>Code</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html> """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())

#<html>
#<head>
#   <title>About me</title>
#</head>
#<body>
#<h1>About Me</h1>
#<h4>My Hobbies</h4>
# <a href="http://www.google.com"> hello world </a>
# <a href="http://www.nytimes.com">byeworld </a>
#<ul>
#   <li>Cooking</li>
#   <li>Gym</li>
#   <li>Code</li>
#</ul>
#</body>
#</html>
```

I get an output of :

```
About me


About Me
My Hobbies


Cooking
Gym
Code
```

Which is the basics of what I want, but I want it to extract the two URL's as well in the plain text.

I tried using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
print(link['href'])
print(soup.get_text())
```

And

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("a")
    for link in soup.final_all('a'):
print(link.get('href'))
print(soup.get_text())
```

I am just getting really confused on how to do this. If someone could help?

Answer (score 1):

The first code chunk should work as long as you indent the code after the for loop. In python, indentation is how you specify code blocks, so anything indented exactly one tab more than the for loop will get run every time the loop iterates.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
print(soup.get_text())
```

Should print:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.nytimes.com

<


About me


About Me
My Hobbies
 hello world
byeworld

Cooking
Gym
Code
```

Note that you have an extra `<` in your html as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost ok. For selecting all `<a>` tags with `href` attribute, you can use CSS selector `soup.select('a[href]')`. Then just iterate found elements and print URLs and text inside them:

```
html = """<html>
<head>
    <title>About me</title>

</head>

<body>
<h1>About Me</h1>

<h4>My Hobbies</h4>
<a href="http://www.google.com"> hello world </a>
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com">byeworld </a>

<ul>
    <li>Cooking</li>
    <li>Gym</li>
    <li>Code</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html> """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print([(a['href'], a.text.strip()) for a in soup.select('a[href]')])
```

Prints:

```
[('http://www.google.com', 'hello world'), ('http://www.nytimes.com', 'byeworld')]
```